# If $X \sim N(0,1)$, why is $E(X^2)=1$?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

If $X$ is a normally distributed with mean $0$ and variance $1$, expectation of $X$ equals $0$ but why is $E(X^2)=1$?

Comment: An easy response: $P(X^2>0)=1$ so how could $X^2$ have mean $0$?

Answer (score 7):

For any random variable $X$ with a finite second moment,
$$
\operatorname{Var}X=\operatorname EX^2-(\operatorname EX)^2
$$
so that $\operatorname{Var}X=\operatorname EX^2$ if $\operatorname EX=0$.

In our case, $\operatorname EX^2=\operatorname{Var} X=1$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

Compute $$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^2 \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}  {\rm e}^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}\right)dx$$

**Hint to hint:**

Note that 
$$ \int x^2   {\rm e}^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}dx = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{2}} {\rm erf}\left( \frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right) - x {\rm e}^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} + \mathcal{C},$$
with [**erf**](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erf.html) being the error function defined by:
$$ {\rm erf}(z)  =\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_0^{z} {\mathrm e}^{-t^2} dt, $$
which can be viewed as **special** function (that is, it has clear, proven properties and numerical computer implementation).

Comment: This is not a hint, this is a definition

Comment: @MTurgeon That's my WHOLE point! Get to the actual calculation, instead of looking for nice ways out of it, like in the other answers :).

Comment: @MTurgeon: It's not a definition, it's a consequence of what is often referred to as the law of the unconscious statistician.

Comment: Hint to the hint: integrals like $\int x^2 \exp(-x^2/2) dx$ are addressed via integration by parts or differentiation by an artificial parameter: introduce $a$ into the exponent as $\exp( -a x^2/2)$, evaluate the integral, and take derivatives with respect to $a$. Oh, and statisticians *hate* the erf() function, it is on a wrong scale as it is does not correspond to the standard normal distribution.

Comment: @StasK Surely. All successful methods are equal in God's eyes. :) feel free to direct the user to them within MSE (tons of related places) or elsewhere. (No, nobody hates erf, they are just used to one language and are uncomfortable speaking other people languages. :))

Comment: @StefanHansen Of course, it depends on your definition of expectation. That $E_{F_Y}(Y)=E_{F_X}(X^2)$, where $Y=X^2$, is definitely a theorem, but they both have different definitions

Answer (score 1):

Another way of seeing this: If $X$ is standard normal, then $X^2$ is chi-squared with one degree of freedom. The expected value of a chi-squared being equal to the degrees of freedom, the result follows.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of variance for a random variable $X$, $var(X) = E[(X - \mu)^2]$, since $\mu = 0$, it's obvious that $var(X) = E[X^2]$.