# How to Compute $E[(W_t)^2(W_s)^2] $ , with $W_t$, $W_s$ are standard Wiener Process

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, expectation, brownian-motion

I can compute $E(W_tW_s)$, but I cannot compute $E[(W_t)^2(W_s)^2] $. please help me! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:**

1. For $t>s$, $f(W_t-W_s)$ and $f(W_s)$ are independent random variables with some measurable function $f$ since $W_t-W_s$ and $W_s$ are independent (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8742/are-functions-of-independent-variables-also-independent)).
2. $W_t-W_s\sim\mathcal N(0,t-s)$ for $0\le s< t$.
3. The fourth moment of the Gaussian random variable $\xi\sim\mathcal N(0,\sigma^2)$ is equal to $3\sigma^4$ (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1917647/proving-ex4-3%CF%834)).

**Edit:**

Without loss of generality, let us assume that $t>s$. Then
\begin{align*}
\operatorname E[W_t^2W_s^2]
&=\operatorname E[(W_t-W_s+W_s)^2W_s^2]\\
&=\operatorname E[((W_t-W_s)^2+2(W_t-W_s)W_s+W_s^2)W_s^2]\\
&=\operatorname E[(W_t-W_s)^2W_s^2]+2\operatorname E[(W_t-W_s)W_s^3]+\operatorname EW_s^4\\
&=\operatorname E(W_t-W_s)^2\operatorname EW_s^2+2\operatorname E(W_t-W_s)\operatorname EW_s^3+\operatorname EW_s^4.
\end{align*}
Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thank you Cm7F7Bb but I still cannot compute.

Comment: Can you help me compute specifically.

Comment: @OoshiOsoto You should include your attempt and where you get stuck in the question. Then we will know what kind of help you need. I updated my answer with more details.

Comment: I got it. Thank you so much, Cm7F7Bb.

Comment: @OoshiOsoto You're welcome! Since you're new to the site, I'd like to remind you that you can [accept](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) this answer if it helped you. But you can also wait until a better answer comes along.